# マルチスレッドプログラム

Tags: c++, マルチスレッド

for文等を用いて、スレッドを複数作成したいのですが、エラーが出てしまい作りきれません。
途中までのコードを添付します。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
void ThreadController::Process_Thread(){
　　　　vector<ThreadSet> threadData;           // 各スレッドのデータを格納
　　　　ThreadSet oneData = { 0 };              // 1つのスレッドのデータを格納
　　　　vector<thread> threads;                 // 複数スレッドを格納

　　　　int dataNum = 0;                        // スレッド数を格納
　　　　int i = 0;                              // ループ用変数

　　　　// スレッド数の入力
　　　　cout << "スレッド数" << endl;
　　　　dataNum = Set_IntNumber();

　　　　// 各スレッドのデータを入力
　　　　for (i = 0; i < dataNum; ++i) {

　　　　　　　　cout << "名" << endl;
　　　　　　　　cin >> oneData.threadName;

　　　　　　　　cout << "タイム" << endl;
　　　　　　　　oneData.intervalTime = Set_IntNumber();

　　　　　　　　// スレッドデータに追加
　　　　　　　　threadData.push_back(oneData);
　

　　　}
    // スレッド実行
    for (i = 0; i < dataNum; ++i) {
        thread threads(Count_SpecifyInterval, threadData[i]);
    }

　　　　// 終了を待つ
　　　　for (thread &th : threads) {
    　　　　th.join();
　　　　}

}


int ThreadController::Set_IntNumber(){
int intervalTime = 0;                   // 入力された実行間隔を格納する変数

do {
    // 実行間隔の入力
    cout << ">";
    cin >> intervalTime;

    // 数字以外が打たれたときエラーを返す
    if ((cin.fail()) || (intervalTime < TIME_MIN)) {
        cin.clear();

        // バッファを空に
        while (getchar() != '\n');

        cout << "正の整数のみ入力してください" << endl;
        intervalTime = ERROR;
    }
    else {
        // エンターキー読み捨て
        getchar();
    }

// 正の数でない場合再入力
} while (intervalTime < TIME_MIN);

return intervalTime;
}

void ThreadController::Count_SpecifyInterval( ThreadSet& dataSet ){
int i = 0;                              //

while ( i < COUNT_MAX ) {

    // 動作の待機
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(dataSet.intervalTime));

    // カウントの加算、表示
    ++i;    
    cout << dataSet.threadName << ":" <<i << endl;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
oid ThreadController::Process_Thread(){

vector<ThreadSet> threadData;           // 各スレッドのデータを格納
ThreadSet oneData;              // 1つのスレッドのデータを格納
vector<thread> threads;                 // 複数スレッドを格納
thread oneThread;

int dataNum = 0;                        // スレッド数を格納
int i = 0;                              // ループ用変数

// スレッド数の入力
cout << "スレッド数" << endl;
dataNum = Set_IntNumber();

// 各スレッドのデータを入力
for (i = 0; i < dataNum; ++i) {

    cout << "名" << endl;
    cin >> oneData.threadName;

    cout << "タイム" << endl;
    oneData.intervalTime = Set_IntNumber();

    // スレッドデータに追加
    threadData.push_back(oneData);

}

try {
    // スレッド実行
    for (i = 0; i < dataNum; ++i) {
        threads.push_back(thread (Count_SpecifyInterval, threadData[i]));
    }
}
catch (exception &ex) {
    cerr << ex.what() << endl;
}
// 終了を待つ
for (thread &th : threads) {
    th.join();
}

}
```

いろいろいじっていたらこれで出来ました。
以上です。

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> vector<thread> threads;                 // 複数スレッドを格納
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> // スレッド実行
> for (i = 0; i < dataNum; ++i) {
>     thread threads(Count_SpecifyInterval, threadData[i]);
> }
> ```

`vector<thread> threads`と`thread threads`と同名別変数を定義しています。
`thread`を作成し`vector<thread>`に格納するには

```
threads.emplace_back(Count_SpecifyInterval, threadData[i]);
```

と記述します。